# How would you make HTML or Javascript or if need be PHP code open up view-source?

Tags: javascript, php, html, nginx, browser

How would you make HTML or Javascript or if need be PHP code open up view-source?
I want users to be able to click a link on my site and have them able to view the source code of the page in a clickable link.
The goal of the view source function is to prove to the user that the website is HTML only and has no tracking / backend to the user by viewing the HTML. This is for users who might known a little bit of code or might not know how to open view source. But more so to increase user confidence in the website

These are the code snippets I currently have

```
 <script>
                        var viewSourceLoc = "view-source:https://" + window.location.hostname;
                        document.getElementById("page-source-link-top").href = viewSourceLoc;
                        document.getElementById("page-source-link-bottom").href = viewSourceLoc;
                        function openLink() {
                                 window.open(viewSourceLoc);
                        }
                        openLink();
                </script>
```

```
     <p>When in doubt
                <a id="page-source-link-top" target="_blank" href="view-source:https://mbps.ctptech.dev">View Page Source>
        </p>
```

```
<input id="view-page" type="button" onclick="openLink()">
```

Neither of them work nor do they open a new page which it should.
Could this be a browser limitation?

Comment: For security reasons, the view-source protocol is no longer supported in new versions of internet explorer  (unless additional permission is granted). For chrome, it seems still ok if with human intervention [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767742(v=vs.85))

Comment: @KenLee I'm really not concerned about IE as it is obsolete. And doesn't have the function I'm making this website for.  I'm wondering for example if you can trigger a key event simulation for the window to open up or another type of work around. I'm using Chrome and making this for Chromium

Comment: I see. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may use file_get_contents of PHP to get the source codes of the URL and then display them in the textarea.

Hence, please use :

```
<form action="" method=POST>
<table border=0><tr><td colspan=2>View Soure:
<tr><td>URL: <td><input name=url> (e.g. http://www.google.com)   
<tr><td><td><input type=submit value="Go!">
</table>
</form>


<?php 
if ($_POST["url"]!="") { 
$html2 = file_get_contents($_POST["url"]);
?>
<textarea style="width:100%;height:200px;" id=sourcecodex><?php echo $html2;?></textarea>
<?php } ?>
```